# Value of joystick reduces when I send it over serial

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I've got two arduino cards and two bluetooth bluesmirfs. I am currently trying to read value from a joystick and send it over to the other arduino card and use that value to control my servo motor.

Here's my code.

```
       //Master Code
void loop()
{
    yVal = analogRead(yAxis);   (value between 0 and 1023)
  if(bluetooth.available())  
  {

    bluetooth.print(yVal);  
  }
  else if(Serial.available())  
  {

    Serial.print(yVal);
  }
  delay(100);
}



//Slave code
void loop(){
  while(Serial.available())
  {

    int c = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("Joystick value: ");
    Serial.println(c);
    int val = map(c, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    Serial.print("Map value: ");
    Serial.println(val);

      myServo.write(val);
    }
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Instead of getting something between 0 and 1023 I get something below 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fundamental lack of understanding of how serial communications works is what you have.

Serial sends bytes. You are attempting to read an int. The two don't match. Not only that, but you are sending the value as text, not a number, so you're interpreting it as gibberish.

My suggestion: do the `map` on the master not the slave, and send a raw byte between 0 and 255 not a string of text between "0" and "1023".

```
bluetooth.write(map(yVal, 0, 1023, 0, 255));
```

Comment: I noticed my mistake right after I posted this, but thank you for clearing some doubts :)